# preseed and install third party software

Tags: preseed

I'm doing an automatic installation of Ubuntu Desktop with a preseed file.

What do I need to put in my preseed file to get the same result as checking the "Install third party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware..." option in the interactive installer?